# Display dhtmlxtree in more than one place

Tags: dhtml, dhtmlx

I've created hhtmlxtree, displayed correct using below code:

```
<script>
  var myTree;
  myTree = new dhtmlXTreeObject("treeboxbox_tree","100%","100%",0);
  myTree.setImagePath("/library/dhtmlxTree/codebase/imgs/dhxtree_skyblue/");
  myTree.setImagePath("/library/dhtmlxTree/skins/terrace/imgs/dhxtree_terrace/");
  myTree.setXMLAutoLoading('customer/tree');
  myTree.setDataMode("json");
</script>
<div id="treeboxbox_tree"></div>
```

I want to display same tree in more than one place like '#treeboxbox_tree'. How to do this without initialize object every time for a tree.

Answer (score 0):

In case of DHTMLX components, you will need to run the init code for each place where you need to have a tree. You can't just clone the already created component.

Comment: Ya i know this. but i want to know is it possible to display a tree at more than one place without initialize object more time?